# How do I Recoll Search my NTFS partition?

Tags: unity, ntfs, recoll

I have multiple OS in my desktop in which I use recoll and recoll lens for desktop search on Ubuntu.

I want to search my **NTFS** (Windows) partition from Ubuntu desktop. How can I do it?

I have looked in to preferences but don't know how to add Windows partitions in that which
can be search from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Once you mount the windows partition (it's probably already mounted under /media/...) you can add it to your recoll index through the recoll settings gui just like any other folder.